# Can't display image in PHP

Tags: php, image, echo, src

I am using this code to display an image.
    `echo "<img src=\"".$row["image"]."\">";`

Printing `$row["image"]` gives:

```
https://www.lesechos.fr/medias/2017/04/19/2080617_hopital-les-candidats-a-la-presidentielle-divergent-sur-les-effectifs-web-0211985257133_300x160.jpg
```

Which is a valid source when I type it in my browser.

However, no image is displayed... What is wrong?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Does lesechoes.fr allow hotlinking? Check your browser console

Comment: *"Printing $row["image"] gives"* - Which is what you asked for and it did its job.

Comment: What is the final markup? everything from your question should cause it to work, but there are all kinds of HTML/CSS things that could be affecting the output.

Comment: Okay I'll check that. So the image is displayed when you run the php code?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show an image, you need to use a `img` tag. An URL won't be enough. What about :

```
<?php 
echo'<img src=" '.$row["image"].' " alt="my image" />';

/* after edit, I saw that you are using code below */
// echo "<img src=\"".$row["image"]."\">";
// seems fine though
// what about this ->

$path_to_img = $row['image'];
echo "<img src=\"$path_to_img\" alt=\"my image\" />"; /* just added `alt` and last slash to be fully compliant */

?>
```

> what does source inspector show as html output ?

I just tested and hotlinking is fine, `img`shows up (kind of an hospital hallway).

Comment: edit his question after answer... 1st line was **not** here. Otherwise, answer is just stupid :)

Comment: yes :) his initial question didn't have the 1st line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43501647/1 - `echo "<img src=\"".$row["image"]."\">";` does have it. @Don'tPanic didn't do anything wrong. Edit: But OP stated: *"Printing `$row["image"]` gives:"* which is exactly what they asked for ;-)

Comment: and answer too :)

Comment: reallyyyyy weird ! well, sorry about that, but really could not see 1st line at 1st peek...

Comment: What is unclear? The image does not show up, but the echo is good I think. What are your opinion?

Answer (score -1):

you have to print the image url in html `src` attribute:

```
echo "<img src='images/." $row['image']. "'/>";
```

Comment: Please add a description to your code snippet,.